# removing scientific notation ONLY for the zero values when printing a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, printing, formatting

Right now my array prints like this:

```
  [[ 1.5531e-01 -4.6594e-02  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00]
 [-4.6594e-02  1.5531e-01  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00]
 [ 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  4.0381e-01  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00]
 [-0.0000e+00 -0.0000e+00 -0.0000e+00  1.9826e+03 -5.9479e+02 -0.0000e+00]
 [ 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00 -5.9479e+02  1.9826e+03  0.0000e+00]
 [ 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  5.1549e+03]]
```

What I would like is:

```
[[ 1.4531e-01 -4.6594e-02  0           0           0           0         ]
 [-4.6594e-02  1.4531e-01  0           0           0           0         ]
 [ 0           0           4.0381e-01  0           0           0         ]
 [ 0           0           0           1.9826e+03 -5.9479e+02  0         ]
 [ 0           0           0          -5.9479e+02  1.9826e+03  0         ]
 [ 0           0           0           0           0           5.1549e+03]]
```

Key differences:

- top row is aligned
- zero values show up as "0", without the negative sign.

I'm printing out a lot of arrays, so I would prefer to have it be something that you can set instead of having to pass every array through a function in order to format it.
Is there something from np.set_printoptions that has this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can specify a `formatter` in `np.set_printoptions`, according to [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).
The line of code below, sets a right padding to number equal to zero, otherwise prints them in scientific notation, keeping the sign.

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'all': lambda x: '{:<11d}'.format(int(x)) if x == 0 else "{:+.4e}".format(x)})
```

This is the output you get:

```
[[+1.5531e-01 -4.6594e-02 0           0           0           0          ]
 [-4.6594e-02 +1.5531e-01 0           0           0           0          ]
 [0           0           +4.0381e-01 0           0           0          ]
 [0           0           0           +1.9826e+03 -5.9479e+02 0          ]
 [0           0           0           -5.9479e+02 +1.9826e+03 0          ]
 [0           0           0           0           0           +5.1549e+03]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I used the formatter but ended up turning it into a string to align it.

`np.set_printoptions( formatter={'all': lambda x: '{:<9s}'.format(" 0. ") if x == 0 else "{: .2e}".format(x)}) `

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please have a look at this section from the help site: [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).